# How to model couchbase schema to store app specific metadata?

Tags: app-store, schema, metadata, couchbase

How to model couchbase schema to store app specific metadata?

Similar to [42matters](https://42matters.com/app-market-data)

We are planning to construct the following structure to query the documents based on bundleid and value.

```
{
  "doc-type": "App-Metadata", ----> (From App Store API)
  "bundleid": "com.whatsapp",
  "value": {

  }
}{
  "doc-type": "App-Looklike", ----> (From App Store API)
  "bundleid": "com.whatsapp",
  "value": {

  }
}{
  "doc-type": "Internal-Metadata", ----> (From MyApp)
  "bundleId": "com.whatsapp",
  "value": {

  }
}
```

Is there any better schema to model beyond this?

Comment: If you're primarily querying by `bundle-id` and `doc-type`, consider using document IDs of the form "doc-type::bundle-id" so you can find the documents using efficient `get` operations (which may be faster than N1QL queries -- try it and see how it works for you app.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything specific wrong with that schema. You might want to call the field you use to specify the type of each document, "type". That's the usual practice.